# What are the ethics for the following?

Tags: regression, neural-networks

If I programmed a regression type machine learning algorithm would there be any ethics in predicting the whole dataset versus the test set which is a subset of the dataset? I would strictly like to know ethics I am well aware of the programming.

Comment: Are you sure you meant "ethics"? I can't see any ethical implications in your question

Comment: @Firebug Like for casting a prediction it wouldn't be unethical to use the whole dataset?

Comment: You mean if it's unethical to do something wrong on purpose?

Comment: Is your question if you train on the whole dataset and then predict for the test dataset that you in fact trained on? If so, doing it and being transparent about it, will be looked at as useless poor quality work that nobody takes seriously (and it will be hard to even get the results published - but of course there's studies like that in the literature). Doing it and misrepresenting it would seem like research misconduct/unethical.

Comment: More so in classroom setting, because i have a project, and I find it weird to run a .fit(dataset), and .predict(dataset) but my partner did that how do I approach them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the test data and the training data separate.

Predicting for the *test part of the dataset* and measuring its accuracy is the standard procedure to see how well your final model performs with out-of-sample data.

It would then be unreasonable to go back and change your model based on this result, but you might decide to throw your model away and collect new test data.

Also predicting for the *training part of the dataset* and measuring its accuracy is not unreasonable to compare how your model performed on in-sample data.  Usually it will be better than accuracy on out-of-sample data, precisely because the model was optimised on this data. But this is not the accuracy you care about.

Combining the two would be unreasonable, as it loses the information from the out-of-sample test, and it can be manipulated both by making the test set smaller and by deliberately overfitting on the training data.